# How can we express that a partial order is more complete than another one?

Tags: complex-numbers, order-theory

Suppose we have two partial orders $R$ and $I$ on $\mathbb{C}$ (conplex numbers) such that:

- $R$ is a total order on $\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers).
- $I$ is also a total order on $\mathbb{R}$ and, additionally, on $\mathbb{I}$ (imaginary numbers).

Is there a technical term fore expressing that $I$ is *more complete* than $R$ in the sense that it has more pairs in its domain?

Would there be a different terminology for the following cases?

- The case where the hierarchy defined by $I$ for $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as $R$'s.
- The case where the hierarchy defined by $I$ for $\mathbb{R}$ is different from $R$'s.

Answer (score 3):

From [Partially ordered set - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Linear_extension):

> A partial order $\leq^*$ on a set $X$ is an **extension** of another partial order $\leq$ on $X$ provided that for all elements $x$ and $y$ of $X,$ whenever $x \leq y,$ it is also the case that $x \leq^* y.$ A **linear extension** is an extension that is also a linear (i.e., total) order.

Apart from Wikipedia, it seems to be surprisingly hard to find a reference for this general use of the term *extension,* except in the special case of a linear extension. Even Wikipedia's definition occurs under the latter heading. Order theory aside, however, the term *extension* is used fairly widely in mathematics, with a meaning that is at least vaguely similar to the one given in Wikipedia. I can't imagine anyone objecting to it. We'll see!

Fortunately, in the case you're interested in (at least, in the first of the two cases you listed), $I$ *is* a linear extension of $R.$ So there is a well-established technical term that says exactly what you want.

It's not clear to me what would be meant by $I$ having (in your words) *more pairs* than $R$ when it is not a superset of $R,$ as seems to be implied by this sentence in the question:

> The case where the hierarchy defined by $I$ for $\mathbb{R}$ is different [from] $R$'s.